# Copia de seguridad o imagen de disco?

Tags: windows, windows10

Se me rompió la pantalla del portátil y el servicio técnico me dice que me lo formatea. Debería hacer una copia de seguridad del disco duro o una imagen de disco duro?

Answer (score 0):

Con una copia de seguridad del disco duro le bastará, una copia de imagen de disco no hace falta, es una copia más completa que incluye actualizaciones del sistema operativo, si te instalan el windows10 no hace falta que hagas una imagen de disco.

**¿Qué es una copia de seguridad de imagen de disco?**

> Este es un tipo de copia de seguridad muy simple de configurar donde
>   normalmente solo tiene que seleccionar una unidad completa, una
>   partición o una máquina completa que normalmente hace una copia de
>   seguridad de toda la selección que ha seleccionado.  Algunos programas
>   como NovaBACKUP, por ejemplo, le permiten realizar copias de seguridad
>   de los cambios desde la última copia de seguridad completa de
>   recuperación de desastres. Donde las copias de seguridad de imágenes
>   de disco realmente brillan es en un tipo de desastre completo.

**¿Qué es una copia de seguridad de nivel de archivo?**

> Las copias de seguridad de nivel de archivo básicamente se reducen a
>   la selección de algunos archivos y carpetas de los que desea hacer una
>   copia de seguridad y luego a dónde desea que vayan las copias de
>   seguridad de nivel de archivo. El tipo de copia de seguridad de nivel
>   de archivo generalmente permite opciones más granulares para la copia
>   de seguridad y restauración de cosas como Exchange, SQL, Estado del
>   sistema (Registro, Active Directory y otras cosas), junto con la
>   capacidad de excluir muchas otras cosas que probablemente No quiero
>   realizar copias de seguridad a diferencia de la mayoría de las copias
>   de seguridad de imágenes de disco. Las copias de seguridad a nivel de
>   archivo también suelen ofrecerle una forma más flexible de realizar
>   copias de seguridad, programación y copias de seguridad normalmente
>   más pequeñas que las copias de seguridad de imágenes de disco.

[Documentación](http://novabackup.novastor.com/blog/difference-between-file-backup-and-image-backup/)

Answer (score 0):

Si es un servicio técnico decente, ellos te harán la copia de seguridad.

Si no te lo hacen cambia de lugar.